# Fluentd logging driver sends unstructured log message

Tags: fluentd

My environment has a setup where docker container logs are forwarded to fluentd, then fluentd forwards to splunk.

I have a issue with fluentd, some of the docker container logs are not in structured format. From the documentation i see that:
fluentd log driver sends the following metadata in the structured log message:

container_id, 
container_name, 
source, 
log

My issue is few of the logs have unstructured metadata information:
for example:
Log 1:

```
{"log":"2019/03/12 13:59:49 [info] 6#6: *2425596 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 10.17.84.12, server: 0.0.0.0:80","container_id":"789459f8f8a52c8b4b","container_name":"testingcontainer-1ed-fwij4-EcsTaskDefinition-1TF1DH,"source":"stderr"}
```

Log 2:

```
{"container_id":"26749a26500dd04e92fc","container_name":"/4C4DTHQR2V6C-EcsTaskDefinition-1908NOZPKPKY0-1","source":"stdout","log":"\u001B[0mGET \u001B[32m200 \u001B[0m0.634 ms - -\u001B[0m"}
```

These two logs have different order of metadata information(log1-[log, conatiner-name, container_id, source])(log2- [container_id, conatiner-name, source, log]). Because of this i'm getting some issues in splunk. How can i resolve this to get same order of metadata info?

my fluend config file is

```
<source>
  @type  forward
  @id    input1
  @label @mainstream
  @log_level trace
  port  24224
</source>

<label @mainstream>

<match *.**>
  type copy
  <store>
    @type file
    @id   output_docker1
    path         /fluentd/log/docker.*.log
    symlink_path /fluentd/log/docker.log
    append       true
    time_slice_format %Y%m%d
    time_slice_wait   1m
    time_format       %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
    utc
    buffer_chunk_limit 512m
  </store>
  <store>
   @type s3
   @id   output_docker2
   @log_level trace

   s3_bucket bucketwert-1
   s3_region us-east-1
   path logs/
   buffer_path /fluentd/log/docker.log
   s3_object_key_format %{path}%{time_slice}_sbx_docker_%{index}.%{file_extension}
   flush_interval 3600s
   time_slice_format %Y%m%d
   time_format       %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
   utc
   buffer_chunk_limit 512m
  </store>
</match>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [fluent-plugin-record-sort](https://github.com/sampointer/fluent-plugin-record-sort)?

Or you can use [built-in record_trandformer plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/filter_record_transformer) like the following if you know all keys in a record:

```
<source>
  @type dummy
  tag dummy
  dummy [
    {"log": "log1", "container_id": "123", "container_name": "name1", "source": "stderr"},
    {"container_id": "456", "container_name": "name2", "source": "stderr", "log": "log2"}
  ]
</source>

<filter dummy>
  @type record_transformer
  renew_record true
  keep_keys log,container_id,container_name,source
</filter>

<match dummy>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

UPDATE(not tested):

```
<source>
  @type  forward
  @id    input1
  @label @mainstream
  @log_level trace
  port  24224
</source>

<label @mainstream>
<filter>
  @type record_transformer
  renew_record true
  keep_keys log,container_id,container_name,source
</filter>
<match *.**>
  @type copy
  <store>
    @type file
    @id   output_docker1
    path         /fluentd/log/docker.*.log
    symlink_path /fluentd/log/docker.log
    append       true
    time_slice_format %Y%m%d
    time_slice_wait   1m
    time_format       %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
    utc
    buffer_chunk_limit 512m
  </store>
  <store>
   @type s3
   @id   output_docker2
   @log_level trace

   s3_bucket bucketwert-1
   s3_region us-east-1
   path logs/
   buffer_path /fluentd/log/docker.log
   s3_object_key_format %{path}%{time_slice}_sbx_docker_%{index}.%{file_extension}
   flush_interval 3600s
   time_slice_format %Y%m%d
   time_format       %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
   utc
   buffer_chunk_limit 512m
  </store>
</match>
</label>
```

Comment: I have added fluentd config file in question, can you please suggest me what changes do i need to do?

Comment: Updated my answer.